# jquery google maps adaption of marc grabanski's code

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm stuck with the adaption of the code below.

What I'm trying to do is to pull out the click function from the JS created Li's so i can make other div's on the page with a class of .myclick shows the message below the point on the map.

Additionally - I would like the selected marker's zindex be reset to bring it to the fronte
front.

Ideas more than welcome,

```
$.getJSON("/ajax/event-locations.php?id=111&action=listpoints", function(json) {
                    if (json.Locations.length > 0) {
                        for (i=0; i<json.Locations.length; i++) {
                            var location = json.Locations[i];
                            addLocation(location);
                        }
                        zoomToBounds();
                    }
                });
function addLocation(location) {
                    var point = new GLatLng(location.lat, location.lng);        
                    var marker = new GMarker(point);
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                    bounds.extend(marker.getPoint());

                    $("<li />")
                        .html(location.name)
                        .click(function(){
                            showMessage(marker, location.name);
                        })
                        .appendTo("#list");

                    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
                        showMessage(this, location.name);
                    });
                }

function showMessage(marker, text){
                    var markerOffset = map.fromLatLngToDivPixel(marker.getPoint());
                    $("#message").hide().fadeIn()
                        .css({ top:markerOffset.y, left:markerOffset.x })
                        .html(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

to pull out the click function you can simple remove this code

```
                $(".event")
                    .html(location.name)
                    .click(function(){
                        showMessage(marker, location.name);
                    });
```

Comment: I did try that, but if i change the <li /> to .event (which is a class in each of the divs I wish to click to show their related map point) it gives me this error: $(".event").html(location.name).click is not a function

Comment: see my edited answer but it will bind click event to all the divs of .event class

Comment: Thanks jimy, but i'm afraid that still gives the error I posted before

Comment: I tried removing the .html(location.name) and adding in a fixed variable for marker but this did not work either

Comment: like this: 
$(".event").click(function(){
     var marker = 1;
     var text = 'some text';
       showMessage(marker, text);
      }) but still nothing